# jQuery, given a Variable with DIV with items, how to scroll an Item to the Left

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following

```
<div id="big" style="width:100%">
 <div id="slider">
  <div class="item" id="item1"><img src="some50x50.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item" id="item2"><img src="some50x50.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item" id="item3"><img src="some50x50.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item" id="item4"><img src="some50x50.jpg" /></div>
 </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {text-align:center;float:left;width:50px;}
```

The ID=BIG DIV can be of random width, 500px, 800px, etc...based on the browser size

What'd I'd like to be able to do with jQuery is slide an item, like item 3, all the way to the left of the div id=slider.

Where I'm stuck is how to find the offset of the item to know how far to slide.

If would be great if there was a way to say Move item3 all the way to the left of DIV ID Slider...

Ideas?

Comment: what's wrong with `float:left;` ?

Comment: this is going to be a jQUery function... All the items are displaying. And then when you click an item, that item needs to scroll all the way to the left. An Animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but this should get you started:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slide').click(function() {
        var bigLeft = $('#big').position().left;
        var item = $('.item:eq(2)');
        var itemLeft = item.position().left;
        var itemTop = item.position().top;
        item.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            float: 'none',
            display: 'inline',
            top: itemTop,
            left: itemLeft
        }).animate({
            'left': bigLeft
        });
    });
});
```

Basically, jQuery makes it so that you don't actually need to know how far to slide your item, you only need to know its final destination.  You'll also have to tinker with the item's position when you do the animation, since you won't be able to animate it the way that you want while it's floating left.

Once you've set a firm position for the item, you just need to call `.animate()` and tell it to animate the item's left position to match that of your big div's left position.

Here's a demo showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/Jbrqh/

Comment: That's a pretty interesting approach. Any thoughts on reverting? This moves it, what about moving it back? thanks!

Comment: This will just make it jump back to its original position (rather than animating it) but you could just remove the css position and give it float:left again.  See a demo here (happens on alternating clicks of slide): http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/2U2A7/  You could also try recording the left position before sliding it, and then just animate it back to that position.